# Drivers for Wacom Bamboo tablet on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bamboo

I would like to use my Bamboo tablet on my newly installed windows 7 box. However I definitively only want have the drivers to be installed. I don’t want all the additional software which is provided by Wacom in the standard software Installation package.

I already tried different installation packages from the Wacom webpage, but I have not found a package which does not install all the additional apps (Adobe AIR etc). I also have not found an option to disable the installation of the undesired apps in the installer .

Have I missed something? May someone give me a hint on how to get/install the drivers only?

Comment: Have you tried the generic drivers that are no doubt offered by Microsoft?

Comment: @Ramhound: Where can I find them? Or do you mean the Drivers which are installed automatically?